# Function Returning Int Despite a Different Return Type Definition

Tags: c, struct

So I'm a little confused here. I'm working on a bigger project, but ran into a few problems, so I wrote a little test case using a simple struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int property1;
}test;

int main(){
    test testing = getNumber();
    printf("%d",testing.property1);
    return 0;
}

test getNumber(){
    test testing = {2};
    return testing;
}
```

All I'm trying to do is read a property from the test struct returned from getNumber(). However, the compiler complains with the following error:

> test.c(8) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'test'

So my question is: why is this function trying to return an int despite me specifying a test return type? How do I fix this? Am I just blind to something simple?

Comment: You're missing a prototype

Comment: Oh geez.. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks lol. wow.

Comment: @PaulR: I 'd hate to see that being copy/pasted into the answer box by someone else.

Comment: @Paul R: With slight elaboration, that's the answer. Please post it as such.

Comment: You might want to crank up your compiler's warning flags to 11, just `gcc -Wall` would have told you your real problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a prototype:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int property1;
}test;

test getNumber(void); // <<< missing prototype

int main(){
    test testing = getNumber();
    printf("%d",testing.property1);
    return 0;
}

test getNumber(void){
    test testing = {2};
    return testing;
}
```

Comment: Yes -- or you could just define `getNumber` before `main`.  In the absence of recursion, there's always an order that makes separate declarations unnecessary.  Which is preferred is matter of taste and style.

Answer (score 2):

The error message here is a bit ambiguous. The default return type of a c function is `int`. Compiler is reporting that it cannot make the conversion from `int` to `test`. But in fact, it failed because it didn't know what `getNumber()` is. Compiler error message should have been a bit clearer saying undefined call to `getNumber()` or some thing on those lines.

C compiler works on a top to bottom approach. What ever variables used, function calls made should be known to it before hand. So when compiler sees the following statement -

```
test testing = getNumber();
```

until this point it doesn't know what `getNumber()` is. So, you have two options making compiler happy.

1. Either forward declare the function declaration.
2. Or move the function definition above `main()`.